# Failed to overload operator +=

Tags: ruby, operator-overloading

I've defined a Person class (name, age). I've tried to overload += operator on the @age instance variable, but I did not manage. Here my script attempt :

```
class Person

    def initialize(name, age)
        @name = name
        @age = age
    end

    def age+= (value)
        @age += value
    end

    def to_s
        return "I'm #{@name} and I'm #{@age} years old."
    end
end

laurent = Person.new "Laurent", 32
puts laurent
laurent.age += 2
puts laurent
```

And this the error I've got in terminal :

```
person.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected tOP_ASGN, expecting ';' or '\n'
    def age+= (value)
             ^
person.rb:15: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end
```

So, what's wrong ?

Thanks in advance. And sorry if this may be a too obvious question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define `+` operator instead and you get `+=` automatically.

But in this case you don't need to override the `+` operator. The `age` member is just a number, so it already has everything defined. What you're missing is a `attr_accessor`.

```
class Person
    attr_accessor :age

    def initialize(name, age)
        @name = name
        @age = age
    end

    def to_s
        return "I'm #{@name} and I'm #{@age} years old."
    end
end

laurent = Person.new "Laurent", 32
puts laurent
laurent.age += 2
puts laurent
```

You only need to override the `+` operator in case you want your class to behave like a number and be able to add to it directly like this:

```
laurent = Person.new "Laurent", 32
laurent += 2
```

But is not very readable in my opinion in this case.

Comment: That's worked, thank you :). Just for my culture : how can just overload the + operator just against age ? And can this work with several members (age, height, weight) ?

Comment: You cannot. You can add a method `grow_older(years) begin @age += years end` for example to change the age.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that you get `+=` "automatically" because `a += b` just expands to `a = a + b`.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Ok, but a = value is still different from a = a + value. That's why I did not find it from myself.

Comment: I've just discovered that I could just use attr_writer instead of attr_accessor : if I don't want the age/name to be edited :)

Comment: I've also noticed that overloading = operator also defines -=, *=, /=, <<=, ... operators :)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @detunized you need to overload + operator to get += operator automatically.

Furthermore your operator definition should not contain the name of the class, it should be

```
def +(value)
    @age + value
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still got an error with your solution (line 19)

Comment: Answer to life is 42, but we are still searching for the right question? My answer can be as good as the question that you ask! You asked operator overloading and I provided the answer, but it seems that you were not sure about the question

Comment: I am sure about the question, but when I changed the script in order to implement your solution, I got an error. Perhaps I've not well done the process, but I got a syntax error.

Comment: I noticed that my syntax error was because of my Ruby version (lowest than 1.9). Anyway, I did not manage to just overload the + operator, even when define outside class Person. Any help, for my culture ?